# Redirect based on input values in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement, input

I have two inputs, one named `name` and the other `pass`.
I would like to do something like the following pseudo code:

```
IF name="NAME1" AND pass="PASS1" THEN REDIRECT TO profil.php
```

Comment: Please note that as a security feature, this is a bad idea. Anyone code just enter the adress to `profil.php` in their browser and visiting it without knowing the correct value for `name` and `pass`.

Answer (score 2):

*I have 2 inputs, one named: "name", and the other: "pass".*

Fetch the fields using either `POST/GET or SESSIONS` and then use `header();` for redirection.

An Example:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "">
Name:<input type = "text" name = "name">
Pass:<input type = "text" name = "pass">
<input type = "submit" name = "sub" value = "submit">
</form>
```

Redirection:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($name === 'NAME1' AND $pass === 'PASS1'){
header("Location:profil.php");
}else
echo "Credentials not matched.";
}
?>
```

Remember that `header()` must be called before any other output (that is, before any HTML code or any `echo`).

[PHP Manual: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: As this code looks, the `header` call comes after actual content. That will not work. Perhaps they are meant as two separate code blocks? Then you can separate them with a HTML comment in between (`<!-- -->`).

Comment: @Anders tried and tested that before posting it, works just fine. If you can think of editing it better, be my guest! `^_^`

Comment: The tricky thing with `header` is that they may work just fine and then suddenly stop working unless you use them right. Added a little warning to your answer (of course you can revert it if you want to). Thank you!